# How to use networkx algorithm with my custom graph datastructure?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx, graph-databases

I have a [graph database](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ajgu) with a [Gremlin query engine](http://gremlindocs.com). I don't want to change that API. The point of the library is to be able to study graphs that can not fully stay in memory and maximize speed by not falling back to virtual memory.

The query engine is lazy, it will not fetch an edge or vertex until required or requested by the user. Otherwise it only use indices to traverse the graph.

Networkx has another API. What can I do to re-use networkx graph algorithm implementations with my graph?

Comment: I want to avoid to construct the networkx graph. I think it's the easiest solution.

Comment: This project implements a similar thing, maybe you can get some ideas from there: https://github.com/LogicalDash/gorm "gorm serves its own special variants on the networkx graph classes: Graph, DiGraph, MultiGraph, and MultiDiGraph. Every change to them is stored in an SQL database."

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do - my guess is use e.g. `all_shortest_paths` with your graph. But you should be able to do all that in Gremlin, no? i.e. not sure what the point is. If you really want to use some networkx code, it mostly talks to the public `Graph` APIs, so if your graph exposes those (or a thunk layer translates them), then you should be able to pass your graph in to most of those functions and they'll probably work. Maybe not as you expect though... networkx has fundamentally different expectations about what's in memory....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about extending your Graph API.

- Hopefully the code translates from one implementation to another in which case copy-paste'ing from the algorithms section might work for you.  (check the licenses first)
- If you want to use existing code going forward you could make a middle layer or adapter class to help out with this.
- If the source code doesn't line up then NetworkX has copious notes about the algorithms used and the underpinning mathematics at the bottom of the help pages and the code itself.

For the future:
Maybe you could make it open source and get some traction with others who see the traversal engine as a good piece of engineering.  In which case you would have help in maintaining/extending your work.  Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks! It's opensource, just did not want to spread it like that. The "tranversal engine" is Tinkerpop's Gremlin query language ported to Python. It's still work in progress https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ajgu.

Comment: Also, what I need is feedback about getting networkx working with another framework, from what I've seen the code of networkx is really meant to be used as is or forked.